# Replace text in Outlook template before being displayed

Tags: vba, email, templates, replace, outlook

I created an Outlook template in which I want to replace certain parts.

This works if I `.display` the template before replacing the information.

If I replace before displaying, it only replaces some of the information.

Below is a section of my code:

```vb
With Email

    .To = AppLog.Cells(BatchRow, 23).Value
    .Subject = Replace(Email.Subject, "<Service>", BatchServiceNumber)
    .Subject = Replace(Email.Subject, "<BatchNumber>", BatchNumber)
    .HTMLBody = Replace(Email.HTMLBody, "%Examiner%", AppLog.Cells(BatchRow, 22).Value)
    .HTMLBody = Replace(Email.HTMLBody, "%Service%", BatchServiceNumber)
    .HTMLBody = Replace(Email.HTMLBody, "%BatchNumber%", BatchNumber)

    'Priority info:
    If BatchServiceNumber = "2P" Or BatchServiceNumber = "2PS" Then

        .HTMLBody = Replace(Email.HTMLBody, "%P%", "Priority ")
        .HTMLBody = Replace(Email.HTMLBody, "%Priority%", "<br> Please note that this Priority Service has a deadline of two days.<br><br>")
```

The subject information, %Examiner%, %Service% and %Priority% are replaced, but %BatchNumber% and %P% do not get replaced **unless** the email is displayed beforehand.

I don't want to display the email if any fields/documents are not found.

Comment: "I don't want to display the email if any fields/documents required are not found" - can't you check that before creating the email?

Comment: This is the current solution that I have implemented and I agree that it is best practice. I am mostly curious to understand the origin of what appears to me as a bug?

Comment: How are you initially creating the mail?  Can you add the code that does that?

Comment: Do you see any difference in the `HTMLBody` string before and after calling the `Display` method? Are you sure that such entries exist before calling the `Display` method?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, do not continuously read and set the `HTMLBody` property as if it were a local variable - accessing that property is fairly expensive and is subject to various checks each time you set it. Use a local variable to read it first, perform multipls replacements, then set the property once.

Remember to property HTML-encode all strings you set.

And lastly, as a general rule of thumb, when replacement does not work, check in the debugger that the string you are working with does have a matching substring: it might be broken by a carriage return etc.

Answer (score 0):

`.GetInspector` may serve the same purpose as `.Display`.

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub replace_test()

Dim Email As MailItem

Dim filePath As String
Dim templateName As String

Dim filePathName As String

filePath = "C:\Users\userid\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates"
Debug.Print filePath

If Right(filePath, 1) <> "\" Then
    filePath = filePath & "\"
    Debug.Print filePath
End If

templateName = "BatchService.oft"

filePathName = filePath & templateName
Debug.Print filePathName

Dim BatchServiceNumber As String

BatchServiceNumber = "Other"
BatchServiceNumber = "2P"
'BatchServiceNumber = "2PS"

Dim BatchNumber As String
BatchNumber = "12345"

Set Email = CreateItemFromTemplate(filePathName)

With Email

    Dim olInsp As Inspector
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    
    '.To = AppLog.Cells(BatchRow, 23).Value
    
    .subject = Replace(Email.subject, "<Service>", BatchServiceNumber)
    .subject = Replace(Email.subject, "<BatchNumber>", BatchNumber)
    
    '.HtmlBody = Replace(Email.HtmlBody, "%Examiner%", AppLog.Cells(BatchRow, 22).Value)
    .HtmlBody = Replace(Email.HtmlBody, "%Examiner%", "AppLog.Cells(BatchRow, 22).Value")
    .HtmlBody = Replace(Email.HtmlBody, "%Service%", BatchServiceNumber)
    
    .HtmlBody = Replace(Email.HtmlBody, "%BatchNumber%", BatchNumber)
    
    ' Without .GetInspector I had to change the placeholder
    '.HtmlBody = Replace(Email.HtmlBody, "%Batch Number%", BatchNumber)

    'Priority info:
    If BatchServiceNumber = "2P" Or BatchServiceNumber = "2PS" Then
        .HtmlBody = Replace(Email.HtmlBody, "%P%", "Priority ")
        .HtmlBody = Replace(Email.HtmlBody, "%Priority%", "<br> Please note that this Priority Service has a deadline of two days.<br><br>")
    End If

End With

Email.Display

End Sub
```